# Using "version" in Chefs windows_package resource

Tags: windows, chef-infra

I develop a package, and it's on my ftp server, in folders with links like this:

```
ftp://domain.com/app/v1.0/app.msi
ftp://domain.com/app/v1.1/app.msi
ftp://domain.com/app/v1.2/app.msi
```

What's the best way to make it easy to install any version of the app? Right now I have:

```
windows_package 'app.msi' do
  source 'ftp://username:password@domain.com/app/v1.2/app.msi'
end
```

Chef documentation says:

> :install
>
> Default. Install a package. If a version is specified, install the specified version of the package.

So how do I make the source ftp path change with the version property? Or is there a better way altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really make both work like that, You could do something like this I guess:

```
windows_package 'app.msi' do
  version '1.2'
  source lazy { "ftp://username:password@domain.com/app/v#{version}/app.msi" }
end
```